# Progressive Matrix question - shaded and unshaded circles in squares

Tags: pattern, visual, progressive-matrix

[image]

[This puzzle](https://m.media-amazon.com/images/S/aplus-media/vc/375271ba-31ae-40fe-93e8-63b64d3a902c.__CR0,0,300,300_PT0_SX300_V1___.jpg) is part of the openly available questions from a book. I'm trying to solve it, but cannot find any solution to it. The book inside preview says the answer is top right one (two solid circles diagonal and one empty circle bottom left). Answer [is here](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1641525312) (patterns at play answers section question 9)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And the correct answer is....

> [image]

Reason

> If you look at the matrix, you will find that each block has a corresponding pair with them. The second image of the pair is exactly opposite to the first one in a sense that the circles are present at the same location with colors inverted. eg-> If you look top left corner square, you see the square mentioned below.
>  [image]

continue...

> So its corresponding pair would be the following image mentioned below. We now have to find this image. We see that this image is in top row and 3rd column. [image]

continue...

> Similarly we find all the other pairs. The only square without any pair is 2nd row 1st column  and its pair is as provided in the solution